# how to append a column with different row count into a data frame in R?

Tags: r, vector

Suppose there is a data frame with a fixed number of row, for example

```
a <- as.data.frame(c(1:7))
```

And there is another vector with fewer (or bigger) number of row:

```
b <- c(1:4)
```

Then it is not possible to add b as new column into a:

```
a <- cbind(a, b)
```

Here is the output:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 7, 4
```

Where the following result is expected:

```
1      1      1
2      2      2
3      3      3
4      4      4
5      5     NA
6      6     NA
7      7     NA
```

Comment: Because the data.frame had 7 rows

Comment: What would you like the output to be? Filled with NAs?

Comment: Try `rowr::cbind.fill(a, b, fill = NA)`

Comment: Yes, actually the problem is: data frame row count differs from new column, as you can see from the question title.

Comment: This works: rowr::cbind.fill(a, b, fill = NA)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can do this easily with `cbind.fill` from `rowr`

```
rowr::cbind.fill(a, b, fill = NA)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
a <- 1:7
b <- 1:4
n <- max(length(a), length(b))
length(a) <- n                      
length(b) <- n

df <- data.frame(cbind(a, b))
```

Comment: The only part that you haven't copy/pasted from the dupe (`data.frame(cbind(a, b))`) is a very bad practice for data frames.

Comment: Wow!! Believe it or not, I actually wrote it down from scratch! When I dont know an R function that does something, I usuallly break it down in smaller chunks and try to figure it out in base R. I didn't like `as.data.frame(c(1:7))` so I used `1:7` whereas " ... fewer (or bigger) number of row (sic)" led me to compare the lengths. Yes, it was a quick fix and probably very inefficient (but maybe not important for the lengths the poster asked for), but I've never claimed to be an expert so perhaps I'm a dupe, indeed!